How can I award a player an additional Feat?
One of my characters has a background which is that they want to one day become a Chef and own their own kitchen. It seems that a variation of the Chef feat would work great for this, and so I am tempted to allow them to gain a version of this (minus the +1 Con) outside of the usual Leveling rules.  However, I am unsure the best way to make them work towards this.
Are there any suggestions in the rules (either official, or 3rd party) as to mechanics to allow a character to learn additional feats/skills? Maybe a series of Skill check rolls etc?

Related: Can player characters teach each other the Magic Initiate feat or other feats?, How unbalanced is it to hand out Feats/ASIs in place of Magic Items?, With the training from the DMG can I receive any feat in any level?

Check out Other Rewards in the DMG
The Dungeon Master's Guide has a section titled Other Rewards (starting on page 227) about non-monetary and non-magical item rewards for adventures. Of particular relevance is the entry on pg. 231, Training.

A character might be offered special training in lieu of a financial reward. [...]
 A character who agrees to training as a reward must spend downtime with the trainer (see chapter 6 for more information on downtime activities). In exchange, the character is guaranteed to receive a special benefit. Possible training benefits include the following:

The character gains inspiration daily at dawn for 1d4+6 days.
The character gains proficiency in a skill.
The characters gains a feat.


Hook up the character with some training. Personally, I would provide training to all the PCs, allowing each to choose one of a few selected Feats that are roughly as powerful as Chef; with the excuse that these are the abilities the available trainers can teach.
Good luck!

The key point here being to keep it equal and balanced, so the other players don't fall behind or feel slighted.

Employ a character-centered plot hook
This is the perfect opportunity for a restaurant-themed quest for the whole party to enjoy helping their buddy achieve personal goals instead of just smiting evil or collecting loot. (And a party-wide buff to short rest healing won't hurt for motivation, either.)
The greatest chef in the kingdom promises to reveal his secret recipes to anyone who can rescue his son from the rat-people.
A quiet village has a haunted ruin where a magical restaurant once stood before a horrible murder, and there's a legend that whoever can uncover its secrets and put the ghosts to rest will inherit its mystical culinary power.
The famed Culinary College requires applicants to provide a sample of their best work, but after gathering all the ingredients for the character's signature dish, they are stolen in a goblin raid. We have to go get them back from the dungeon.

We had a number of campaign arcs in one of the campaigns I was in where the reward wasn't XP or loot, it was the DM saying "OK, pick a feat or an ASI (score improvement) as the reward for quest completion."
